# Java replaceAll and regex

Tags: java, android, replaceall

I'm working on Android and I want to replace all ocurrences of a certain {character} in a String with another String.
For example, if the character we're talking about is 'a'and the replacement is "12" then:

```
Input : There are {a} months in a year.
Output : There are 12 months in a year.
```

I don't know how to deal with the `replaceAll` method and `regexes` ...

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try it? Did you search for examples of `replaceAll` usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `string.replace("{a}", "12")` it replaces **all** occurrences of {a} by 12 in a string and doesnt take regular expression. If you need to search patterns then use `replaceAll`

Answer (score 4):

At this purpose you can use  `String.format`

```
int aInt = 12;
String.format("There are {%d} months in a year",  aInt );
```

Answer (score 1):

As you don't need use regex here, vishal_aim's answer is better for this situation.

The first attempt with `replaceAll` would be

```
String str = "There are {a} months in a year.";
str.replaceAll("{a}", "12");
```

but it doesn't work because `replaceAll` takes a regex and `{}` are special characters in regex so you need to escape them:

```
str.replaceAll("\\{a\\}", "12");
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I was Looking for .. I actually tried it this way but I thought escaping would be with one slash only, and it did not compile!!

Comment: Next time please add it to a question. It will be obvious what you tried.

Comment: but why do you need to use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`?

Comment: @vishal_aim yes, using `replace` makes more sense. Thank you.

Comment: it seems to me that `replace` only works for one `char` and I need to replace a String "{a}" ...

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "There are {a} months in a year.";

str.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("{a}"), "12");
```

**EDIT**:

[java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) methods returns a literal pattern String for the specified String.